# Where and how are an Objective-C class's methods stored?

Tags: objective-c, methods, objective-c-runtime

I know that when an object is instantiated on the heap, at the least enough memory is allocated to hold the object's ivars. My question is about how methods are stored by the compiler. Is there only one instance of method code in memory? Or is the code generated an intrinsic part of the object in memory, stored contiguously with the ivars and executed?

It seems like if the latter were the case, even trivial objects such as `NSString`s would require a (relatively) large amount of memory (`NSString` inherits methods from `NSObject`, also).

Or is the method stored once in memory and passed a pointer to the object which owns it?

Comment: Every object (at least the normal ones) has a class.  There is a pointer from the object to its class object (which of course has it's own pointer to a class object, but we won't go there).  The class object is shared by all objects of that class, and the methods of the class are tied to the class object.

Comment: why you care about this?

Comment: The thing you have to understand is that how an object is stored in memory is an implementation detail.  Apple could choose to make every object an array of 64-bit integers, and every method a pointer to some random hunk of OS code for all you should care.  All you have to worry about is whether Objective-C does what it says on the box.

Comment: @BryanChen: Being inquisitive (about how your tools work in particular) may be the single most important trait a programmer can have. Why do you care why he's curious?

Comment: I mean it is implementation detail. Most of the time your code should not rely on implementation detail because they may change. Unless you have serious performance problem or find a (potential) bug, you should be able to write code without any knowledge of these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a "standard" Objective-C runtime, every object contains, before any other instance variables, a pointer to the class it is a member of, as if the base Object class had an instance variable called:

```
Class isa;
```

Each object of a given class shares the same `isa` pointer.

The class contains a number of elements, including a pointer to the parent class, as well as an array of method lists. These methods are the ones implemented on this class specifically.

```
struct objc_class {
    Class super_class;
    ...
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists;
    ...
};
```

These method lists each contain an array of methods:

```
struct objc_method_list {
    int method_count;
    struct objc_method method_list[];
};

struct objc_method {
    SEL method_name;
    char *method_types;
    IMP method_imp;
};
```

The `IMP` type here is a function pointer. It points to the (single) location in memory where the implementation of the method is stored, just like any other code.

---

**A note:** What I'm describing here is, in effect, the ObjC 1.0 runtime. The current version doesn't store classes and objects quite like this; it does a number of complicated, clever things to make method calls even faster. But what I'm describing still is still the *spirit* of how it works, if not the exact way it does.

I've also left out a few fields in some of these structures which just confused the situation (e.g, backwards compatibility and/or padding). Read the real headers if you want to see all the gory details.

Comment: Later versions of ObjC can optimize some common (meaning common to Apple) method calls with a vTable.  Most others used to get looked up in the SEL cache and returned in 2.0.  That might have changed with all this new magic isa stuff in the latest versions of the runtime.

Comment: The cool thing here is that `objc_class`, et al. live in writable memory space.  Methods can be added at runtime and one `IMP` can be replaced with another.

Comment: Oh okay, just a follow-up question about the ObjC runtime: if the Class in memory only contains an array of its own methods, are inherited methods executed by actually physically moving up the chain of superclasses until it's found? Having a little bit of knowledge about procedural programming in assembly, I have a serious fascination with the low-level details of how objects and classes are managed at runtime. <3

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman: Yes, that's precisely how it works. If a method isn't present in any of the lists in a class, the runtime will continue searching in the `super_class`.

Comment: Although in reality for speed Apple uses a selector map cache so the runtime doesn't have to manually search tables every time you make a method call. Interestingly enough, in the old days, Object Pascal and Think C ("with objects") originally did table searches for every method call, which made function dispatch much slower.

Comment: Right - as noted at the bottom of my answer, I'm describing the original ObjC runtime for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Hi, could you please me why use list/array but not dictionary/map to store methods? As hash is faster then table search and better for add/remove method of a class. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Methods are stored once in memory. Depending on the platform, they are paged into RAM as needed. If you really want more details, read the Mach-O and runtime guides from Apple. It's not usually something programmers concern themselves with any more unless they're doing something pretty low-level.

Objects don't really "own" methods. I suppose you could think of it as classes owning methods, so if you have 400 NSStrings you still only have one copy of each method in RAM.

When a method gets called, the first parameter is the object pointer, self. That's how a method knows where the data is that it needs to operate on.

Comment: -1 Objective-C's method dispatch is not like C++.  You can't just leave it at "they get dumped into RAM".

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Actually Objective-C's method dispatch is pretty similar to C++. The biggest difference is that the method pointer is determined somewhat more dynamically at runtime rather than via an indexed table lookup.

Comment: @EricS ObjC method dispatch is opposite to C++ (runtime dispatch vs compile time dispatch). Is is kinda similar to virtual function but still big difference.

Comment: I wouldn't call that opposite. They both do essentially the same thing, mapping a class+method to a function pointer, but Objective-C is more dynamic and flexible whereas C++ is faster. Note that I wrote a lot of code in the old days before OOP became popular and we used to do similar things ourselves using function pointer tables. The cool advantage there was that we could override methods on an object-by-object basis rather than for an entire class.